# Back to specific view controller in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say I have five view controllers and I want to go to the specific view controller

RootViewController ==> FirstViewController ==> SecondViewController ==> ThirdViewController ==> FourthViewController(Modally presented having a button) 
and all other controllers I connected through push method.
My task is I want to go to the firstViewController from FourthViewController when button is clicked. Any help?

```
        for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
        if controller.isKind(of: HomeViewController.self) {
            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```

this is the code I have done.

Comment: use poptoviewcontroller and specify the viewcontroller if you are ising navigationcontroller

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050782/how-to-show-a-specific-vc-more-like-navigate-to-a-stack-of-vc/49066910#49066910

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add delegate in FourthViewController:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.delegate.popToFirstVC()
}
```

Add `func popToFirstVC()` in ThirdViewController.
Use [popToViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller):

```
func popToFirstVC() {
    if let firstViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

or better

```
guard let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers else {
    return
}

for firstViewController in viewControllers {
    if firstViewController is FirstViewController {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

There is still such an option.
Add an Observer for this function and call where necessary.
But I would do it only in the most extreme cases.

```
func popToThisVC() {
    if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        topController.navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is 1 in viewControllers[1] ?

Comment: Are all your controllers in Navigation stack?

Comment: Yes all my navigation controllers are in stack

Comment: Do you have any method which uses protocols to go back to specific view controller because it always works on my app?

Comment: I think that using the protocol is good if you need to go back to the previous VC. If there are many controllers, then it is necessary to transfer the whole chain from the first VC to the last VC, which seems to me not very good.

Comment: but all of these is not working is not working in modal presented view controller. These methods are working fine only in push method.

Comment: Thanks but I will try tomorrow because my company is closed :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166872/discussion-between-v-rohit-and-maxwell).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned connected, hence I reckon you used storyboards and segues, in that case why not create an unwind segue?
It's a bit hard to show you snippet of unwind segue here via text only but I think [Unwind segue blog from medium](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f) has your answer